# I am looking for a way to keep the bottom navigation icons color in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, vuetify.js

The color of the icons in the bottom nav always changes when I click another one, am looking for a way to keep the colors

[image: bottom nave]

[image: bottom nav]

Comment: Please include the portions of your HTML/CSS/JS relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can disable active-class in your code.